# CSS works in debugger, but not on live site

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Please review my [Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/U3aXK/).

Click on a calendar day with an event (orange square).

You'll notice that the date box, is at the bottom of the window.

In the stylesheet, there's a snippet like this...

```
.calendar *{
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    vertical align: top;
    behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
    }
```

...the `vertical-align: top;` should bring that box to the top of the window, but it doesn't.

If you add `vertical-align: top;` to the stylesheet in Chrome, then it works fine.

Not sure why this is... Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems to be a height issue. Remove `height: 100%;` from `.calendar .c-specific`

```
.calendar .c-specific {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; <<< Remove this
left: 0;
top: 0;
display: none;
padding: 1em;
behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: Keep on coding brotha! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the line you need to change:

```
.calendar .c-holder .c-grid .c-row .c-day .date-holder {
font-size: 1.3em;
position: absolute;
right: 5%;
bottom: 5%; /*** CHANGE THIS TO TOP ***/ 
behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
}
```